# Simulate samples from a joint cumulative distribution function?

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, probability, sampling

I have a [joint density function](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709705/JointDens.png) for two independent variables X and Y. And I now want to sample new x,y from this distribution.

What I believe I have to do is to find the joint cumulative distribution and then somehow **sample** from it. I kinda know how to do this in 1D, but I find it really hard to understand how to do it in 2D.

I also used the matlab function `cumtrapz` to find the [cumulative distribution function](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709705/CumulativeDist.png) for the above pdf.

Just to be clear, what i want to do is to sample random values x,y from this empirical distribution.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?!

**EDIT:** I have data values and I use 
[pdf bins] = hist3([N Y])

I then normalize the pdf and do

cumulativeDistribution = cumtrapz(pdfNormalize)

And yes (to the comment below) X,Y are suppose to be independent.

Comment: What's the joint density function?

Comment: If your variables are independent, your joint distribution is simply the product of marginals. Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: Do you have analytic formulae for your joint density? Or are you estimating from samples? What are you using to estimate the joint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know how to sample a distribution in 1D then you can extend it to 2D. Create the marginal distribution for *X*. Take a sample from that, say *X*<sub>1</sub>. Then in your 2D distribution fix one variate X=*X*<sub>1</sub> and sample for *Y*, i.e., sample *Y* from 1D distribution f<sub>XY</sub>(*X*<sub>1</sub>, *Y*).

Comment: This works! :) The same is almost done in this very nice .m-file from the MATLAB file exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35797-generate-random-numbers-from-a-2d-discrete-distribution

Comment: This is correct but would you have a solution when only relying on the cdf?

Answer (score 3):

Given a joint distribution in say, two random variable X and Y, you can compute a CDF for X alone by summing over all possible values of Y, i.e. P(X<=x)=Sum[P[X=x_i and Y=y_j],{x_i<=x and all values of y_j}]. Once you have P(X<=x) in hand, there are well-known methods for sampling a value of X, let's call it a. Now that you have a, compute P(Y<=y given X=a)=Sum[P[X=a and Y=y_j],{y_j<=y}]/Sum[P[X=a and Y=y_j],{all values of y_j}]. Sample Y using the same approach that gave you X, yielding Y=b. Done.

The same approach generalizes to more that two random jointly distributed random variable.

Comment: This answer was very helpful to me! This put me on the right path, and I was able to implement this into a useful sampling method for the Kent distribution.