# Sampling from multivariate customised cumulative distribution function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, probability, sampling, cdf

Consider a 5-variate [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (cdf) which I call F.

I want to sample random 5x1 vectors from this cdf in Matlab. F is not a cdf that has been already implemented in Matlab (such as normal, t-student, etc.). Specifically, it is defined as

[image]

I have read several question/answers in this and other forums on how to sample from customised probability distribution functions in Matlab. However,

1) Most of them are for univariate cdf, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894953/matlab-generate-random-numbers-from-custom-made-probability-density-function). The idea is to apply [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). My problem is a bit more complicated because I would need to "invert"a 5-variate function.

2) Another option could be to use [slicesample](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/slicesample.html) as suggested [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35861-how-to-sample-from-custom-2d-distribution) but I don't know how to write the analytical expression of the probability density function in my case.

3) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208667/simulate-samples-from-a-joint-cumulative-distribution-function)'s another idea but specific for the bivariate case.

Could you kindly help me to understand how I can proceed?

Comment: i am not sure if i understand your problem,
you said that you have a CDF which is F(r, sigma_a, sigma_b),
then you want to randomly sample from this function ! 

so your problem is how to make a random 5x1 vector of r and submitting it to F? or  your problem is how to transform this CDF to a proper PDF for custom values of r?

Comment: @user3285148: The code I posted was correct only for independent probabilities. It picked r1, r2 and r4 correctly, but r3 depends on r2 and r5 on r4, so these did not show the correct distributions. I have fixed the code, it's become a bit more complex now, but it seems correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Your link under #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209260/7328782) gives a hint of the solution. It explains the bivariate case when you have a PDF. Here we'll extend this to any number of dimensions, for the case when you have a CDF.

So the process is:

1. Compute the marginal CDF for *r*<sub>1</sub>.
2. Take a random sample using this marginal CDF ([another link you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894953/matlab-generate-random-numbers-from-custom-made-probability-density-function) explains how to do this).
3. Compute the marginal CDF for *r*<sub>2</sub> given *r*<sub>1</sub>.
4. Take a random sample using this marginal CDF
5. Compute the marginal CDF for *r*<sub>3</sub> given *r*<sub>1</sub> and *r*<sub>2</sub>.
6. etc. etc. You see where this is going.

Note that if you have a PDF, computing marginal distributions involves integrating over the remaining variables. So a marginal distribution for *r*<sub>1</sub> requires integrating over *r*<sub>2</sub>..*r*<sub>5</sub>, a marginal distribution for *r*<sub>2</sub> given *r*<sub>1</sub> requires integrating over *r*<sub>3</sub>..*r*<sub>5</sub>, etc.

When you have a CDF, computing the marginal distributions is trivial, as it already integrates the PDF: the marginal distribution for *r*<sub>1</sub> is *F*(*x*,∞,∞,∞,∞). However, obtaining the marginal distribution given one or more variables requires differentiating: a marginal distribution for *r*<sub>2</sub> given *r*<sub>1</sub> requires differentiating along *r*<sub>1</sub>, a marginal distribution for *r*<sub>3</sub> given *r*<sub>1</sub> and *r*<sub>2</sub> requires differentiating along *r*<sub>1</sub> and *r*<sub>2</sub>, etc.

It might be possible to obtain these derivatives analytically (this would be the more efficient solution). Here we use the finite difference derivative approximation instead (this makes it easier to plug in any CDF).

Let's see some MATLAB code:

```
sigma_a = 0.5;
sigma_b = 0.3;
F = @(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)exp(-exp(-r1) - (exp(-r2/sigma_a)+exp(-r3/sigma_a)).^sigma_a ...
                                   - (exp(-r4/sigma_b)+exp(-r5/sigma_b)).^sigma_b);

lims = [-5,10]; % This is the area along all dimensions containing 99.99% of the PDF

N = 1000;
values = zeros(N,5);
for n=1:N
   values(n,:) = sample_random(F,5,lims);
end
```

Here I picked some random values for `sigma_a` and `sigma_b`, and used those to define a function `F` of 5 variables `r1`..`r5`. I figured that the domain of the PDF is the same along all dimensions, I found a region slightly larger than really necessary (`lims`). Next, I obtain 1000 random samples from the distribution `F` by calling `sample_random`:

```
function r = sample_random(F,N,lims)
delta = diff(lims)/10000;
x = linspace(lims(1),lims(2),300);
r = inf(1,N);
for ii = 1:N
   marginal = get_marginal(F,r,ii,x,delta);
   p = rand * marginal(end);
   [~,I] = unique(marginal); % interp1 cannot handle duplicated points, let's remove them
   r(ii) = interp1(marginal(I),x(I),p);
end
```

`delta` is the distance we'll use for the finite difference approximation to the derivative. `x` represents sample points along any one dimension of `F`.

We first define `r` as the vector `[inf,inf,inf,inf,inf]`, we'll use this as the sample locations, and at the end of the function it will contain the random value drawn from our distribution.

Next we loop over the 5 dimensions, in each iteration we sample the marginal distribution for dimension `ii`, given the values for the previous dimensions (which have already been picked). The function `get_marginal` is below. We pick a random value in between 0 and the max of this marginal CDF (note that the max decreases as we pick values of `r` for each dimension, when `ii==1` the max is 1), and we use this random value to interpolate into the inverse sampled marginal CDF (inverse simply means swapping x and y). I needed to remove repeated values from `marginal` because it becomes the `x` in `interp1`, and this function requires the `x` values to be unique.

Finally, the function `get_marginal`:

```
function marginal = get_marginal(F,r,ii,x,delta)
N = length(r);
marginal = zeros(size(x));
for jj=0:2^(ii-1)-1
   rr = flip(dec2bin(jj,N)-'0');
   sign = mod(sum(rr,2),2);
   if sign == 0
      sign = 1;
   else
      sign = -1;
   end
   args = num2cell(r - delta * rr);
   args{ii} = x;
   marginal = marginal + sign * F(args{:});
end
```

This contains quite a bit of complication. It samples the CDF along a given dimension `ii`, at the points `x`, given the fixed values `r(1:ii-1)`.

The complication comes from computing partial derivatives. If we were to compute the marginal distribution for any one dimension without having picked any fixed values yet, we would simply do e.g.

```
marginal = F(inf,x,inf,inf,inf);
```

Having picked one value, we would do

```
marginal = F(r1,x,inf,inf,inf) - F(r1-delta,x,inf,inf,inf);
```

(this is the approximation to the partial derivative along the first dimension).

The code in `get_marginal` does this for `ii-1` fixed values. This requires sampling `F` twice for each of these fixed values, as well as for each combination of `delta` shifts, a total of `n^2` times (for `n` fixed values). The `dec2bin` bit is to get all these combinations. `sign` determines whether to add or subtract the given sample from the running total. `args` is a cell array with the 5 arguments to the function `F`, elements `1:ii-1` are the fixed values, element `ii` is set to `x`, and elements `ii+1:N` are `inf`.

---

Finally, I draw the marginal distributions of the data set `values` (which contains the 1000 elements randomly drawn from the CDF), and overlay with the marginal distributions of the CDF, to verify all is correct:

```
lims = [-2,5];
x = linspace(lims(1),lims(2),300);
figure
for ii=1:5
   subplot(5,1,ii)
   histogram(values(:,ii),'normalization','cdf','BinLimits',lims)
   hold on
   args = num2cell(inf(1,5));
   args{ii} = x;
   plot(x,F(args{:}))
   text(5.2,0.5,['r_',num2str(ii)])
end
```

[image: marginal distributions, input and sampled]

Comment: I have posted an issue with the answer (but it may be me implementing your procedure wrongly). Please advise if you have time. Thanks

Comment: @user3285148: It looks like your "comparison" graph is inverted from the other ones. It starts at -6 and ends at 2, the other ones start at -2 and end at 6. A minus sign issue?

Comment: @CrisLuengo To draw the comparison I used the pre-built function `evrnd`.

Comment: @user3285148: That implements a different equation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/extreme-value-distribution.html. Why not compare to `exp(-exp(-r0))`, which is what you expect the output to be?

Comment: @CrisLuengo : `evrnd` implements draws from this distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution (see PDF and CDF formulas on the right). When `sigma=1`, `F` = joint CDF of 3 i.i.d. Gumbel with scale `0` and location `1`. Hence, when I plot each marginal of `F` against the empirical CDF of `evrnd(0,1,N,1)` I  should get the same thing.

Comment: @user3285148: I don't have the stats toolbox, so cannot compare, but the [documentation to `evrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/evrnd.html) links to the page I linked above, that shows a different equation: `exp(x)*exp(-exp(x))` vs your `exp(-exp(-x))` (ignoring all sigma and mu). Why don't you plot your `exp(-exp(-x))` against `evrnd(x)` and see the difference?

Comment: Interesting: notice that the first equation here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution refers to the PDF and not to the CDF. In my question I reported the CDF. Though, there are flipped signs! In Wikipedia the Gumbel PDF with scale 0 and location 1 is `exp(-x)*exp(-exp(-x))`. In Matlab the Gumbel PDF with scale 0 and location 1 is `exp(x)*exp(-exp(x))`.

Comment: I need to think more, sorry. I didn't expect this. I will post a question on this flipped sign.

Comment: @user3285148: [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GumbelDistribution.html) agrees with MATLAB, I would guess Wikipedia is incorrect with its flipped sign. Interesting discussion on the [Talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Gumbel_distribution).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess that is the issue.

Comment: Could you help me with this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69290732/drawing-from-gev-cumulative-distribution-function-in-matlab