# Drawing from GEV cumulative distribution function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to R random draws in Matlab from the following 3D cumulative distribution function (CDF) [This CDF belongs to the [GEV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) family]

[image]

To do so, I have tried to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908047/sampling-from-multivariate-customised-cumulative-distribution-function-in-matlab)  code to my question as follows:

```
F = @(x0,x1,x2)  exp(-exp(-x0) - (exp(-x1/lambda)+exp(-x2/lambda)).^lambda); 

lims = [-5,10]; 

draws = zeros(R,3);
for r=1:R
    draws(r,:) = sample_random(F,3,lims);
end
```

with auxiliary functions

```
function r = sample_random(F,N,lims)
delta = diff(lims)/10000;
x = linspace(lims(1),lims(2),300);
r = inf(1,N);
for ii = 1:N
   marginal = get_marginal(F,r,ii,x,delta);
   p = rand * marginal(end);
   [~,I] = unique(marginal); % interp1 cannot handle duplicated points, let's remove them
   r(ii) = interp1(marginal(I),x(I),p);
end


function marginal = get_marginal(F,r,ii,x,delta)
N = length(r);
marginal = zeros(size(x));
for jj=0:2^(ii-1)-1
   rr = flip(dec2bin(jj,N)-'0');
   sign = mod(sum(rr,2),2);
   if sign == 0
      sign = 1;
   else
      sign = -1;
   end
   args = num2cell(r - delta * rr);
   args{ii} = x;
   marginal = marginal + sign * F(args{:});
end
```

However, when I plot the empirical marginal CDF of the first component of F for different values of lambda, I get almost identical pictures, which I think should not be the case:

```
clear
rng default
lambda_grid=[0.05 0.4 1];  
slambda=size(lambda_grid,2);
store_draws=cell(slambda,1);
R=10^3; %number of draws
for j=1:slambda
    lambda=lambda_grid(j);
    F = @(x1,x2,x0)  exp(-exp(-x0) - (exp(-x1/lambda)+exp(-x2/lambda)).^lambda); %CDF of epsilon0, epsilon1, epsilon2
    lims = [-5,10]; 
    draws_temp= zeros(R,3);
    for r=1:R
        draws_temp(r,:) = sample_random(F,3,lims);
    end
    store_draws{j}=draws_temp;
end
ecdf(store_draws{1}(:,1))
hold on
ecdf(store_draws{2}(:,1))
hold on
ecdf(store_draws{3}(:,1))
legend('\lambda=0.1', '\lambda=0.5', '\lambda=1')
```

[image]

Therefore, I think I'm doing something wrong. Could you advise?

Comment: I don't really know what a marginal cdf is, but you can see that the three curves are slightly different. Is this difference big or small? That depends on the underlying distribution, but in general I don't see any red flags. Do you have some information that tells you otherwise?